# Finding concepts from a large corpus using Word embeddings

Tags: gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I am trying to find out new concepts in a Corpus from Konkani language.
I had trained two models on 1) a domain specific corpus 2) on newspaper corpus.

I have used Gensim word2vec to train the model however I am unable to get the terms of similar meaning on close proximity in vector space.

The closes words show no relation of being synonym with each other. Their similarity is as good as just some random words.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

How big is your corpus?

For your trained vector to be meaningful, you would need at least 100 million word corpus (assuming about 1-2 million unique words).

You can suspect a sampling method if you had used Negative sampling instead of hierarchical, but I still think that small corpus size is the main problem of yours.